# How do i check if the game was closed?

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to create a game and now i want to check if the game is being closed so i will send a message to the server, how do i do it?
(XNA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (found on [this site](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/44962.aspx))

```
protected override void LoadContent() 
{ 
    Form f = Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle) as Form; 
    if (f != null) 
    { 
        f.FormClosing += f_FormClosing; 
    } 
    base.LoadContent(); 
} 

void f_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{ 
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: This requires referencing the System.Windows.Forms assembly, and it is not portable to Xbox 360.

Answer (score 11):

The correct method is, in your `Game` class, override `OnExiting`:

```
protected override void OnExiting(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Do stuff here...

    base.OnExiting(sender, args);
}
```

The documentation for this method is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.onexiting.aspx

Alternately you could attach an event to `Game.Exiting`.

Or you could override `EndRun`, although this doesn't seem to fire on Windows if the user exits with Alt+F4.

Comment: I don't know about 4.0, but this did not work in 3.1 on Xbox on some cases (eg. quitting via the guide). I used it in my Xbox game to save high scores, and discovered it only saved if I quit the game using my menu option, but not if it's torn down by using the Guide :(