# How to do implement an OnExit like method in my XNA game?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

Is there any method for C# XNA games which detects if the user clicked on the cross button to close the program, or pressed the ALT+F4 keys to close .. ?

The ALT+F4 keys can probably be detected from KeyBoardState, but how do I detect the clicking of the cross button to close the window ?

I need this so that I can shut down all the threads running when the user closes the game through any means .. I currently have some threads still running when the close the game which makes the music still play :P

Please note that the method has to be both Windows and Xbox 360 compatible, as the game is supposed to run on both these platforms (probably Zune too) ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i check if the game was closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997323/how-do-i-check-if-the-game-was-closed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either override the [`OnExiting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.onexiting.aspx) method of the [`Game`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197040.aspx) or susbcribe to its [`Exiting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.exiting.aspx) event.

Example:

```
protected override void OnExiting(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    base.OnExiting(sender, args);

    // Stop the threads
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I tried writing this code in the Game inherited class: ..

Comment: protected virtual void OnExiting(
         Object sender,
         EventArgs args
)
        {
            timeToQuit = true;
            Exit();

        }

Comment: And tried setting a breakpoint to the first instruction, then ran the game and press ALT+F4 to see if I go to that breakpoint .. I did not .. The game just closed naturally .. This means that the game exited to the windows command ALT+F4 to close a window, not because of the code I mentioned above ..

Comment: You need to mark the method as `override` otherwise it will not be called.